# Linking Cells by using Sheet number, not name

Tags: excel-formula

From my research, I'm seeing the only way to link cells between different worksheets is using the sheet's name: `=Sheet1!K12`

But I want to use the sheet number `=Sheet(1)!K12` or something, if that is possible.
My ultimate goal is to replicate a row that exists for Sheet1 for different sheets.

Comment: Why not make each sheet's Name the same as its Number ???

Comment: Aside from changing the names, there is no way for a formula by itself to refer to a sheet by its tab order, that will take vba.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Because the sheet's name is referencing the item description. Sheet1 is the template, but is actually Sheet(7).